# Proving the harmonic series, multiplied by a factor of 1/n, decreases monotically to zero.

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that $\left(1 + \frac 12 + \dots + \frac 1n\right) \cdot \left(\frac 1n\right)$ decreases monotonically to zero.

I have seen one method: to first show that the difference $\left(1 + \frac 12 + \dots + \frac 1n\right) - \log(n)$ decreases monotonically to the Euler-Mascheroni constant, but I was wondering if there is another (perhaps cleaner or more instructive) way of proving the limit is zero.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the arithmetic mean of the numbers $1, 1/2,\ldots,1/n$. If you add a number that is lesser than the others, say $1/(n+1)$, the mean decreases.

The limit is $0$ because

$$\frac{H_n}n<\frac{\log n}n\to0$$

Comment: Good point, ajotatxe.  So we've established the monotonicity of the sequence, but I don't think we can conclude that it decreases to zero?  I think I'd need to compare the growth rates between the numerator and denominator, i.e., 1/n goes to zero sufficiently fast and the numerator, (1 + 1/2  ... + 1/n) increases at a suitably slow rate.  Is there a bound I can use?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

For large values of $n$, the expansion of $H_n$ is $$H_n=\gamma +\log (n)+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{12
   n^2}+\frac{1}{120 n^4}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^6\right)$$ which leads to $$\frac{H_n}{n}=\frac{\gamma +\log (n)}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}-\frac{1}{12
   n^3}+\frac{1}{120 n^5}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^7\right)$$

Comment: Hi Claude - is there anything wrong with my arguing that, for n>1, we have that (1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n) < integral, from 1 to n, of 1/x dx = log(n) - log(1) = log(n), and since log(n) / n goes to zero, Hn / n must go to zero, by the squeeze theorem.  (I apologize if my formatting is off, I am new to this website.  Thanks.)

Comment: @LebronJames. There is absolutely nothing wrong in your argument. My intent was just to show you how the expression was moving to $0$. Cheers :-)

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much, Claude.